# "Word-request" and "word-equivalent"

Tags: feature-request, tags, tagging

I have asked a question to get the female equivalent of "Esq" or "Esquire". 
There is no appropriate tag for my question. I want to create the following tags: "word-request" and "word-equivalent". But, I am not allowed. Hence, I raise the issue here (in Meta) to get the tags created. Please help me.

Link to the question referred to above: [Is there any female equivalent to ‘Esq’ or ‘Esquire’?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336996/is-there-any-female-equivalent-to-esq-or-esquire)

Comment: "Single-word-request" means the substitution of a single word for a couple of words, not of a word for a word.

Comment: Good advice. Done.

Comment: You should read the tag information for [tag:single-word-request] because your understanding of it is incorrect. `Use this tag for questions that are about finding a single word to fit a meaning.` Your question is essentially "Is there a word that means the same as Esquire when applied to a woman?" which is in my opinion a very straight-forward single word request.

Comment: As ColleenV commented, this question is based on the OP's misunderstanding of the SWR (Single-Word-Request) tag.

Comment: Note that if you aren't sure whether the term you're looking for is a single word or two or more words, you can tag the question as both _single-word-requests_ **and** _phrase-requests_. That should cover both possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [synonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonyms) and possibly [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice).

Comment: word-choice is for choosing between a given list of words - not what the OP is after in this case